# New Android Studio: Cannot resolve symbol 'ContextCompat'

Tags: java, android

After updating Android Studio, I found some red rows in my project.

What I have.

I call this method:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
    orangeProgressBar(progressBar);
}
```

Using of red `ContextCompat.getColor()`:
[image]

```
private void orangeProgressBar(ProgressBar pb) {
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(pb.getContext(), R.color.orange);
    ...
}
```

Of course, importing:

`implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'`

`import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;`
[image]

Studio can't import `content.ContextCompat`, because it seems like `android.support.v4.content.` have not this child

Comment: which version of `Android Studio` and `gradle` are you using?

Comment: @VSB, Android Studio 3.1, and gradle:3.1.0

Comment: did you updated your repositories like this: `allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem after updating the Android Studio but the below solution worked for me:

Deleting the `.gradle` and `.build` folder from your respective project directory structure and rebuild the project.I'm not so sure about what it does but i think it deleted all the previous build caches other build related files and regenerated it that's why it's worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! I just:

1) Deleted `.gradle` and `.idea` folder. 

2) Rebuild project.

And now it works!

Comment: Most of the un-scientifi wierd problem in Android Studio gets solved in this way

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the .gradle and .idea did not work for me.
What worked was the following:

In Android Studio close all projects

In the Welcome To Android Studio Screen:

- remove all the projects by clicking the X in the top right corner, or right click, choose "Remove Selected From Welcome Screen"
- Close Android Studio
- Re-open Android Studio,
- Open an existing Android Studio project Navigate to the project
- It re-built and the errors were gone.